# When I use WebView to display content, I got the error: cannot found junit.framework.Assert

Tags: android, android-webview

When I use WebView to display content, I got some error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit.framework.Assert
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:677)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Why WebView uses JUnit Assert, not java assert? so strange! Test method should not be in a production.

BTW, android 4.0 fails.